# ContentDialog isn't available in WinJS 3.0.1

Tags: winjs

I am making a website using WinJS 3.0.1, the last "stable" version as far as I know, and everything worked as a charm until I tried to create a ContentDialog following the instructions from http://try.buildwinjs.com and I discovered that that control is not included in that build, even if it was in previous versions of the library. The dialog will show up with pre 3.0 builds, but they only work on IE, so they are not a viable option.

Why is ContentDialog missing, has it been deprecated? Should I use other control or will it be added again in a coming version?

I've been searching through Microsoft documentation but I haven't found anything that explains why ContentDialog is not longer available, so any info is helpful.